# Regexp Matching in Reducer

Tags: rascal

I'm looking at reducers.

There is a [nice example in the Tutor](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Common/WordCount/CountInLine3/CountInLine3.html) for counting words:

```
(0 | it + 1 | /\w+/ := S)
```

where `S` is some longer string with several words. The reducer returns the count of such words.

I was wondering how to capture the matched substring and use it in the accumulating expression, something like

```
("" | it + e | str e ... /\w+/ := S)
```

so that the result would be the concatenation of all matched substrings.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the capture syntax is with the `<name:regex>` notation:

`("" | it + e | /<e:\w+>/ := S)`

```
rascal>S  ="Jabberwocky by Lewis Carroll";
str: "Jabberwocky by Lewis Carroll"
rascal>("" | "<it>,<e>" | /<e:\w+>/ := S)[1..]
str: "Jabberwocky,by,Lewis,Carroll"
```

or use the for-template syntax instead of a reducer expression:

```
rascal>x = "<for (/<e:\w+>/ := S) {><e>;
>>>>>>>    '<}>";
str: "Jabberwocky;\nby;\nLewis;\nCarroll;\n"
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>println(x)
Jabberwocky;
by;
Lewis;
Carroll;

ok
rascal>
```

Comment: Great. Just a tiny extension: There is this idiom to loop over a list with `<-`. How would I extend the reducer to match all strings from a list, e.g. `("" | it + e | <e:\w+> ... <- L)` where `L` would be a list of strings?

Comment: Just like that. The syntax is "pattern <- generator" so you could have`/regex/ <- myList` and the regex would be tested against every element in order, and every match in every string would trigger a single loop iteration.